# How do I design error codes in c++?

Tags: c++, function, error-handling

I am writing a c-style function:

```
enum {
    EFUNC1,
    EFUNC2,
}

int func0() {
    int err = 0;
    if((err=func1())!=0) {
        // return err or return EFUNC1
    }

    if((err=func2())!=0) {
        // return err or return EFUNC2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

func1 and func2 are c functions and they have their own error codes. What should I do when func1 or func2 return an error? I figure out some ways:

1. Design my error codes. The number of error codes is the sum of func1's and func2's. When the call stack is deep, the number of error codes becomes large.
2. Simply return the result of func1 or func2. There is no way to know which function fails since their error codes may overlap.
3. Design my error codes and the number of the codes is equal to the number of functions. The caller just know which function return error, but he don't know the further reason.
4. Throw an exception wrapping the failed function name and its error code.

What's the best practice?

---

The previous code example is ambiguous. I modified it.

Comment: Your thinking is a bit flawed. Calling `func1` and `func2` is an implementation detail of `func0`. You shouldn't report which function failed, but **why a failure occurred**. That's robust, and a better practice. That way nobody has to go digging into the call graph to know what's wrong.

Comment: if `func1()` fails with an error that needs to be reported to the caller, then why do you even attempt to call `func2` ?

Comment: @tobi303 The example is not incomplete. I am just showing that func0 will call func1 and func2. I haven't added any error-handling codes.

Comment: There's no "the" best practice, but it seems you want something like `enum ErrorDomain = { no_error, func1_error, func2_error, ... }` and `using ErrorT = std::pair<ErrorDomain, int>` or an equivalent. Whether you return `ErrorT` or throw it is up to you and your project standards. `func1_error` is just an example identiffier, you probably should use something specific domain name like `network_error` or `database_error`.

Comment: "not incomplete" is that a typo? otherwise I dont understand the comment and if yes, then my comment still holds: I would not worry about combining two error messages into one. If the calling code has to decide what to do in case of an error (if `func` could decide you would not need to pass the error code) then the function should not continue with `func2` in case there was an error already in `func1`

Comment: @tobi303 it may be useful to continue. The problem with this question is that there is no general answer. One approach that may make sense is to return the most severe return code.

Comment: @user2672165 yes there might be rare cases where it makes sense to continue, but in that case calling the return of `func1` an error code is rather confusing imho. For me error code means only the caller can decide how to continue. If this isnt the case, then why pass the code to the caller at all ?

Comment: You can refine that by adding more specific information, like a file name you was trying to open or a host you was trying to contact. When you have a variety of error-specific data you may consider grouping your errors into C++ classes rather than tagging them with a simple enum. You can either `throw network_error(... your network error info... )` or return an `std::variant` that can hold any of your error types, again depending on your project standards. `int` error codes are just way too restrictive.

Comment: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/using-error-codes-effectively/

Comment: @tobi303 it's typo. i want to correct it but i was told to do it in 5mins. Do you mean func0 should not spread the error code and handle it inside? What if it can't handle the error?

Comment: I believe it was meant that by definition, you shouldn't continue executing `func2` after an error occurred. If you could, then it probably shouldn't be treated as an error

Comment: what I mean is, there are basically two options: Either `func0` knows what to do in case `func1` returns an error, then it does not need to report the error to the caller. Or `func0` does not know what to do in case of an error and returns the error to the caller as soon as it encounters one (and does not continue with `func2`). I would not mix those two.

Comment: @StoryTeller The error codes of func1 and func2 **exactly explain why a failure occurred** .  Say func1 is about creating socket, if it fails, func0 returns ESOCKET_FAIL. The caller knows there is sth. wrong with socket, but it's not detailed enough. Now I offer a choice to let he know the detail by returning the error code of func1. If he don't care the detail, it 's also ok, just `if(func0() !=0 )`

Comment: @PasserBy thats exactly what I meant. If `func0` can decide how to continue after `func1` had an error, then why should it report that error to the caller?

Comment: I suggest you actually phrase your question better than. You asked about reporting which function failed.

Comment: @tobi303 that enlightens me. What would you do if func0 does not know what to do if error occurs?  Combining the error codes of func1 and func2?

Comment: i still dont understand why you want to call `func2` if `func1` had an error. Just imagine you have not 2 but 10 functions that could fail. If you always call all 10 functions (be there an error or not) that would mean the caller has to deal with 2^10 possible error states, ie it gets complicated fast and does not scale at all. Thus I would not continue once there is an error and return only that error code.

Comment: ...or did I misunderstand the "combine the error codes" ? Of course if the values `func1` and `func2` error codes overlap, then `func0` has to deal with that and provide an unambiguous value to the caller.

Comment: I really like approach taken here making use of modern C++: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kLyccSb7Tk

Comment: @tobi303 i said that is typo. Now i modify the code. You did misunderstand "combine the error codes". It's not 2^10 but 20. Even it's 20, it's still large.

Comment: I think you have the XY-problem. In C++, you most often don't use error codes. You return an optional, a variant (of result type and error types), throw, or better yet: take continuations (functors) on what to do in each case.

Answer (score 2):

Why expose the complexity of `func0()` to the caller? Usually the caller is not interested in what happens in the body of the function, he just wants the job to be done.

`func0()` should notify the user on why it failed to complete its goal (to terminate without errors). They are many ways to do that. One example could be this:

```
// On success: Return 0
// On error: Return -1
int func0() {
    if(func1() == -1) {
      printf("Error in func0: func1 returned error code -1");
      return -1;
    }
    if(func2() == -2) {
      printf("Error in func0: func1 returned error code -2");
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that here we don't allow `func2()` to be executed if `func1()` fails, since that might be dangerous.

For instance, if `func1()` is suppose to allocate space for an array that `func2()` is going to use, then let's say that `func1()` fails (because `malloc()` failed). `func2()` should *not* be called, since `func1()` failed in that case, because the array that `func2()` expects to be ready for use, is not available at runtime.

Comment: i modify the code. it's more clear now, sry. Simply returning true or false is easy but it hides the detail. the caller is not interest in what functions func0 calls, but he may be interest in the reason when func0 fails. True and false are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing [tobi303's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419274/how-do-i-design-error-codes-in-c?noredirect=1#comment79796230_46419274), the logic behind error codes is as follows:

1. If a routine (`func0`) will fail when an error occurs in a certain subroutine (`func1`), the routine should stop immediately on error and report back to the caller.

   To do otherwise makes no sense. For example, if `func0` is to make coffee, `func1` is to get some beans and `func2` is to brew, then without the beans, you are just brewing air. Telling someone you can't brew air isn't awfully helpful.
2. If a routine can gracefully handle an error in its subroutine, then its not an error at all for the caller of the routine. In this case, no error should be returned.

So the structure of your program for the first case should be simply

```
int func0()
{
    if(int err = func1())
        return err;
    if(int err = func2())
        return err;
    return 0;
}
```

And the second case

```
int func0()
{
    if(int err = func1())
        handle(err);
    if(int err = func2())
        return err;
    return 0;
}
```